# NestJS 'type' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

This is my code and `'type'` is underlined in red and show me this error:

```
'type' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
```

My code:

```
@ManyToMany(type => RoleEntity, role => role.users, {eager: true})
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Replace `type` with the discard `_`?

Comment: ```@ManyToMany(_type => RoleEntity, role => role.users, {eager: true})``` Like this? Use not would be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Noah said, you can use a discard name like `_` or you can use a blank function. The two approaches would look like so:

```js
@ManyToMany(_ => RoleEntity, role => role.users, {eager: true})
```

OR

```js
@ManyToMany(() => RoleEntity, role => role.users, {eager: true})
```